Get Java code to trigger Windows' CTL lookup / CTL-to-Trusted-Root-CAs migration
I have a Java application that calls System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "WINDOWS-ROOT");, thus triggering the JRE to eventually call the Windows CertOpenSystemStore method, then enumerate and load the certs from the HKLM-backed Trusted Root Certification Authorities cert store to use for its internal validation.
That's great and all, except when dealing with a very clean / recently installed Windows machine where the Trusted Root Certification Authorities only contains ~16 entries. I only recently learned about Windows' Certificate Trust List (CTL) functionality, a hidden mechanism that transparently checks certificate chains against a list of trusted roots that Windows downloads from Windows Update (or elsewhere, if overridden, e.g., by GPO). This enables web browsers to work without complaint with more than a handful of sites, and digitally signed binaries to execute without warnings. Certain operations, like visiting a site in Internet Explorer (but not Edge) additionally cause a CA to be migrated from the CTL to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.
However, I infer that the CTL mechanism doesn't get triggered in the Java workflow because Java doesn't ask Windows to validate a TLS certificate chain—it just validates the chain against the certs it enumerated from the Trusted Root Certification Authorities (CertOpenSystemStore). The end result is sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: : sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target after calling HttpURLConnection::getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);.
Does anyone know of a way to trigger Windows' CTL-to-Trusted Root Certification Authorities migration mechanism? Obviously if there's a native Java way to do this, that'd be ideal, but even if someone knows what Windows C API(s) trigger this, so I could write some JNI, that'd be better than the alternative of telling users to visit a site in Internet Explorer to make sure its root CA will be trusted by the Java application.
Thanks!

Sounds like you do not have Imported the certificate in your jvm

I think you're referring to the default behavior, as if the app didn't override System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "WINDOWS-ROOT");. Indeed, the purpose of this question is to avoid needing to manually import root CAs--be it to the cacerts trust store or the Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

I think what you are looking for would be a security-hole in the operating system. I mean the trust-store is not the place to install new certificates from some program without the explicit user confirmation. Your best bet is to run certmgr.exe with the required parameters from your java-code as a separate process, which will require user interaction/confirmation in any case.

@Hack06 : I don't think so. I'm not attempting to add an arbitrary cert to the Trusted Root Certification Authority cert store, just get one that Windows already trusts via CTL "promoted" from the CTL into the actual Trusted Root CAs cert store.

There is no "java" way of doing what you asked for you need to use C++ or C code to invoke like something below with features that come with panama
project.
import java.lang.foreign.*;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Optional;

public class WindowsCertValidator {
    // Define the library path for Advapi32.dll and crypt32.dll (the libraries needed for Cert APIs)
    private static final String ADVAPI32 = "Advapi32";
    private static final String CRYPT32 = "Crypt32";

    // Foreign linker to access native functions
    private static final Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();

    // Define function signatures for CertOpenSystemStore and CertGetCertificateChain
    static final MethodHandle CertOpenSystemStore;
    static final MethodHandle CertGetCertificateChain;
    static final MethodHandle CertCloseStore;

    static {
        // Load the native methods using Panama Foreign API
        var lookup = SymbolLookup.loaderLookup();
        
        // CertOpenSystemStore (from crypt32.dll)
        CertOpenSystemStore = linker.downcallHandle(
                lookup.find("CertOpenSystemStoreA").orElseThrow(),
                FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS)
        );

        // CertGetCertificateChain (from crypt32.dll)
        CertGetCertificateChain = linker.downcallHandle(
                lookup.find("CertGetCertificateChain").orElseThrow(),
                FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                                      ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS)
        );

        // CertCloseStore (from crypt32.dll)
        CertCloseStore = linker.downcallHandle(
                lookup.find("CertCloseStore").orElseThrow(),
                FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT)
        );
    }

    public static MemorySegment openCertStore(String storeName) throws Throwable {
        MemorySegment storeNameSegment = SegmentAllocator.implicitAllocator()
                .allocateUtf8String(storeName);

        MemorySegment certStore = (MemorySegment) CertOpenSystemStore.invokeExact(MemoryAddress.NULL, storeNameSegment);
        if (certStore.address().toRawLongValue() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to open cert store");
        }
        return certStore;
    }

    public static void closeCertStore(MemorySegment certStore) throws Throwable {
        int success = (int) CertCloseStore.invokeExact(certStore, 0);
        if (success == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to close cert store");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Open the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
            MemorySegment certStore = openCertStore("ROOT");
            System.out.println("Successfully opened Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.");

            // Normally, you would invoke CertGetCertificateChain here to trigger validation
            // and interact with the cert chain, using similar downcalls as CertOpenSystemStore.

            // Close the cert store when done
            closeCertStore(certStore);
            System.out.println("Successfully closed the cert store.");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Thanks for this! It's not clear to me from the documentation (e.g., CertGetCertificateChain) or your example: does this function automatically update the Trusted Root Certification Authorities from the CTL (so long as CERT_CHAIN_DISABLE_AUTH_ROOT_AUTO_UPDATE and CERT_CHAIN_CACHE_ONLY_URL_RETRIEVAL aren't passed to dwFlags), and/or am I expected to pass something in to hAdditionalStore to make that work?
